# Export Runnable JAR file not working

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar

I have read a lot of similar questions but I cant find anything helpful in them, so I have to ask one myself.

I have a program that uses TCP socket connection server and client with a total of 5 classes in one package, two of them have a main method (server and clientGUI).

[image]

But when I use rightclick on server.java -> export -> runnable jar file with server run configuration, it works, I can run it from outside eclipse. But when I do the same for clientGUI.java, nothing happens when I run the clientGUI.jar file.

main method in Server looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server s = new Server();
    s.start();
}
```

but in ClientGUI i only have this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ClientGUI();
}
```

is that the problem? I don't have `start()` in ClientGUI, because nothing happens until user input, and everything related to graphics is coded in the constructor, and the rest is in `ActionPerformed` method that handles buttons.

---

ClientGUI:

```
public class ClientGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1115273859077115660L;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextArea chatBox;

private static Client client;
private JButton resetB;
JButton btnConnect;
JLabel lblGrid;
JLabel lblGrid2;
static int port = 56667;
String IP;
private JTextField txtPort;
private JTextField txtIP;
final JButton readyB;

ClientGUI() {
    super("Client");
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setResizable(false);
    setBounds(100, 100, 945, 750);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setBounds(10, 11, 920, 520);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    readyB = new JButton("READY");
    readyB.setEnabled(false);
    readyB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            lblGrid.setVisible(true);
            readyB.setEnabled(false);
            client.sendMessage(new Message(Message.READY, client.myID, ""));
        }
    });
    readyB.setBounds(784, 461, 126, 48);
    panel.add(readyB);

    BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("img/grid.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lblGrid = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    lblGrid.setText("");
    lblGrid.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
            int x = m.getX() / 40;
            int y = m.getY() / 40;
            if(client.myShots[x][y] == false){
            client.sendMessage(new Message(Message.SHOT, client.myID,
                    (x + 1) + " " + (y + 1)));
            client.myShots[x][y] = true;}
        }
    });
    lblGrid.setBounds(480, 40, 401, 401);
    panel.add(lblGrid);
    lblGrid.setVisible(false);

    lblGrid2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    lblGrid2.setText("");
    lblGrid2.setBounds(40, 40, 401, 401);
    panel.add(lblGrid2);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(493, 681, 437, 20);
    getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    textField.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(10, 542, 210, 159);
    getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    resetB = new JButton("R");
    resetB.setBounds(160, 108, 40, 40);
    resetB.addActionListener(this);
    panel_1.add(resetB);

    btnConnect = new JButton("Connect");
    btnConnect.setBounds(230, 542, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnConnect);
    btnConnect.addActionListener(this);

    JLabel lblIp = new JLabel("IP:");
    lblIp.setBounds(329, 546, 22, 14);
    getContentPane().add(lblIp);

    JLabel lblPort = new JLabel("Port:");
    lblPort.setBounds(329, 580, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(lblPort);

    txtPort = new JTextField();
    txtPort.setText("1234");
    txtPort.setBounds(361, 577, 120, 20);
    getContentPane().add(txtPort);
    txtPort.setColumns(10);

    txtIP = new JTextField();
    txtIP.setText("192.168.0.25");
    txtIP.setBounds(361, 542, 120, 20);
    getContentPane().add(txtIP);
    txtIP.setColumns(10);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(491, 544, 439, 124);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    chatBox = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(chatBox);
    chatBox.setEditable(false);
    chatBox.setLineWrap(true);

    textField.requestFocus();

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ClientGUI();
}

void drawX(JLabel grid, int x, int y) {
    JLabel xg = (new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/x.png")));
    xg.setBounds(40 * (x - 1), 40 * (y - 1), 40, 40);
    grid.add(xg);
    xg.setVisible(true);
    repaint();
}

void drawMiss(JLabel grid, int x, int y) {
    JLabel xg = (new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/miss.png")));
    xg.setBounds(40 * (x - 1), 40 * (y - 1), 40, 40);
    grid.add(xg);
    xg.setVisible(true);
    repaint();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object o = e.getSource();

    if (o == textField) {
        String text = textField.getText();

        client.sendMessage(new Message(Message.CHAT, client.myID, text));
        textField.setText("");
    }

    if (o == resetB) {
    }

    if (o == btnConnect) {
        IP = txtIP.getText();
        port = Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText());

        client = new Client(IP, port, this);
        // test if we can start the Client
        if (!client.start())
            return;
        else
        client.display("Connected!");
        txtIP.setEnabled(false);
        txtPort.setEnabled(false);
        btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
        readyB.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

public void append(String string) {
    chatBox.append(string);
    chatBox.setCaretPosition(chatBox.getText().length() - 1);
}
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client {
private ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
private ObjectInputStream sInput;
Socket socket;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
private static ClientGUI cg;
private static String IP;
private static int port;
int myID;
boolean[][]myShots = new boolean [10][10];

Client(String IP, int port, ClientGUI cg) {
    this.IP = IP;
    this.port = port;
    this.cg = cg;

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
}


public boolean start() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(IP, port);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        display("Server not running!");
        return false;
    }
    try {
        sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + e);
        return false;
    }

    new ListenFromServer().start();

    return true;
}

void display(String msg) {
    cg.append(sdf.format(new Date()) + ": " + msg + "\n");
}

void sendMessage(Message msg) {
    try {
        sOutput.writeObject(msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        display("Exception writing to server: " + e);
    }
}

public void clearMyShots(int id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                myShots[i][j] = false;
}

class ListenFromServer extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        Message cm = null;
        while (true) {

            try {
                cm = (Message) sInput.readObject();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            switch (cm.getType()) {
            case Message.ID:
                myID = Integer.parseInt(cm.getMessage());
                display("Your ID is " + myID);
                break;
            case Message.HIT:

                String[] partHit = cm.getMessage().split(" ");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(partHit[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(partHit[1]);
                int whoShot = cm.getID();
                if (whoShot == myID) {
                    display("HIT: " + (char) (x + 64) + y);
                    cg.drawX(cg.lblGrid, x, y);

                } else
                    cg.drawX(cg.lblGrid2, x, y);
                break;
            case Message.SHOT:
                display("SHOT: " + cm.getMessage());

                break;
            case Message.MISS: {
                String[] partMiss = cm.getMessage().split(" ");
                x = Integer.parseInt(partMiss[0]);
                y = Integer.parseInt(partMiss[1]);
                whoShot = cm.getID();
                if (whoShot == myID) {
                    display("MISS: " + (char) (x + 64) + y);
                    cg.drawMiss(cg.lblGrid, x, y);
                } else
                    cg.drawMiss(cg.lblGrid2, x, y);
                break;
            }

            case Message.DESTROYED:
                break;
            case Message.CHAT: {
                display("Player " + cm.getID() + ": " + cm.getMessage());
                cm = null;

                break;
            }
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is the ClientGUI() class implementing Runnable, or extends Thread? Because if it does, then it means that it is a Thread. If this is the case, then you should add a start() method invocation after the constructor. Could you post some more code of the ClientGUI class?

Comment: @nick.katsip `ClientGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener`

Comment: @nick.katsip i posted the code for client too. Client is created from ClientGUI and it is what handles the server connection and messaging. There's also additional Thread class inside client class.

Comment: You have got 2 main methods.

Comment: @Asalas77 it is clear from the code that you need to invoke the `ClientGUI.start()` method so that the client starts.

Comment: Is your client running from Eclipse? Did you check, that all needed classes are in the resulting JAR? How did you try to execute the executable JAR exactly? Did you try to run your executable JAR from commandline like `java -jar clientGUI.jar`? Is there an error message or exception? When you try to run the JAR from command line with additional main class parameter like `java -jar clientGUI.jar ClientGUI` does the client application run? Did you check the `Main-Class:` entry of your resulting `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file?

Comment: "nothing happens when I run the clientGUI.jar file" -- what output do you get?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? I don't think this is a bad question. So +1.

Comment: @nick.katsip there is not `start()` in clientGUI. It's in client, and client is not created until user tries to connect.

Comment: @nitind i guess i should make it more clear. I double cliecked it. Now that I read other comments I tried running prom cmd and got this http://pastebin.com/j2nMyYRH exception. So it's a problem with textures apparently.

Comment: @user3535778 I do, but I have different run configurations for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the cause was not related to the main method. Following  user @vanje i ran my program from windows command line and it showed IOException reading image files that I forgot to copy to new directory. I did and it is working

Answer (score 0):

To start a Swing application, such as your GUI client, you need to have the following in your main method:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater
(
    new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new ClientGUI();
        }
    }
);
```

Here is a [Hello World Sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java) that will help you understand the minimum necessary to start a Swing app.